# Installing flash for other browsers so it will work with Steam?

Tags: 14.04, steam

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to install flash for other browsers via tar.gz I just don't know where to put the files though so it would work with the steam web browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: @ARUL: Not OT. The solution is not related to a `.tar.gz` file.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, run the following steps:

1. Download the file from [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/completion/?installer=Flash_Player_11.2_for_other_Linux_%28.tar.gz%29_32-bit). You NEED to get the 32-bit version.
2. Extract the tar file. Place it in your home folder.
3. Run: `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/plugins`. This will allow you to install Flash plugins.
4. Run `cp ~/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386/libflashplayer.so ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/plugins`. This will install the flash plugin into your Steam install.
5. Install `libxt6` by `sudo apt-get install libxt6:i386`.
6. ???
7. ***PROFIT!***

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/how-to-get-flash-player-to-work-with.html)